# Zend Framework URL Route not adding domain

Tags: php, zend-framework

got a bit of a problem with Zend not adding the base url into routes i think.

What i have is as follows:

```
application
    modules
        menu

public
    menu
        css
        js
        index.php

    index.base.php
```

I am using the function

```
<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'module1'), 'menu-install'); ?>
```

With the route:

```
$router->addRoute('menu-install', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/install/:modulePath', array('module' => 'menu', 'controller' => 'install', 'action' => 'install')));
```

Which is outputting http://menu/install/module1/ instead of http://localhost:8888/menu/install/module1/

Any ideas whats going on?

Comment: Can you give the route definition for "menu-install" ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add it, added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ro write this(in bootstrap for example)

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setBaseUrl('/');
```

Comment: If i add in the following it seems to work `$front->setBaseUrl('/localhost:8888/' . CURRENT_MODULE . '/');`

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the URL View Helper return only the URI after the without the domain ; than

```
 <?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'module1'), 'menu-install'); ?>
```

Write something like this:

```
 /menu/install/module1/
```

Where:

1. /menu is your "BaseURL" (.htaccess)
2. /install/* is your route content

Perhaps, you have write "http://" before the  ?

An other possibility is that you have a mistake with your parameters "module" and the "Module" mechanics of Zend_Framework...

Aka